# Android - MediaPlayer error: attachnewplayer called in state 64

Tags: java, android, native, audio-player, android-music-player

I am following below post for creating simple music player, but selecting any song from list or pressing prev/next from MediaController is giving below error. I am using Oreo (Andoid 8.1.0 API 27).

```
public void playSong()
{
Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
songTitle=playSong.getTitle();
long currSong = playSong.getID();
Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,currSong);
try
{        
    player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    player.prepareAsync();
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
}
```

}

Error `MediaPlayer error: attachnewplayer called in state 64`

Reference: [Create Simple Music Player](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778)

Comment: On which method call was the exception caught?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to reset player, also have to set setAudioStreamType, so your code will look like below

```
try 
{
    player.reset();
    player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.prepareAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the key to an issue like this is to let people know the list of state:

- 1: ?
- 64: ?
- 128: PlaybackCompleted. I encounter 128, after play was done, then stop and reset are not called before setDataSource is called. I know the sequence of stop, reset, setDataSource, prepareAsync, start was working.
- ?: ?

Comment: If I play again without calling player.reset(); then I get 128.  Doing the reset got away the error.